# Issue and clarification needed with attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, attr-accessible

There is so much written about the security threat of attr_accessible that I am beginning to wonder if I should even have any attributes in it. Here is the issue. I have a `Message` model which has the following:

```
attr_accessible :body,:sender_id,:recipient_id
```

I do not have the `update` or `edit` action in my `messages_controller`. With the `new` and `create` action I am able to create a new message and send it to a recipient. Only users who have logged in and meet certain conditions can message each other. I do that with the help of a `before_filter` and the conditions work fine. The message is stored and can be viewed by the `sender` and the `recipient`. Perfect!

The question I have is that since `:body,:sender_id,:recipient_id` are included in `attr_accessible`, can a malicious user somehow change the `:body,:sender_id,:recipient_id` of the original message? Should I just add these attributes to `attr_readonly` as well so they cannot be modified once saved?

This question has been haunting me for practically all my models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can a malicious user somehow change the :body,:sender_id,:recipient_id
>   of the original message?

This would depend on other things rather than `attr_accesible`. `attr_accesible` will only filter which fields are allowed to be updated using mass assignment. Since you say you don't have any `update` action, then no, there is now way a user can edit a message since you always create a new `Message` through you create action.

But there is something you need to care about. What is `sender_id`? If you do have users in your app and they send messages to each others, then `sender_id` **should not be an accessible field**, since this will allow users to send messages on behalf of other users. You probably want to keep that field off the `attr_accessible` list and do something like this:

```
m = Message.new params[:message] # body and recipient_id
m.sender_id = current_user.id # this is not mass assignment
m.save
.....
```

Comment: sender.id == current_user.id. That is how I have it currently. Is there a threat despite this?

Comment: Why would you put sender_id in the list then? This should not be a field allowed to be mass assignable.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on how your are creating your model's instance. If you use:

```
FooModel.create(params[:foo])
```

then yes, your are not secure because a logged in user may pass additional parameters to the request even if you don't provide explicitly form fields for those attributes.

So, for your case, anyone posting to your "create" action with sender_id, recipient_id (values in the request) will be able to change them **unless you take care about this assignments** in your action.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I do care of assignments in the action. For example, the sender is the current_user, whereas the recipient is obtained through params. But the recipient is obtained through the hidden field and has a set user.

Comment: Then you should remove the sender_id from the attr_accessible and set it explicitly in you action.